# insert node in xml file

Tags: c#, xml

i have a xml file that looks like the following, and i need to edit it in c# to insert a new node:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Users>
    <User>
    <Name>John Smith</Name>
    <test>
        <Date>23.05.2011</Date>
        <points>33</points>
    </test>
    <test>
        <Date>22.06.2011</Date>
        <points>29</points>
    </test>
    </User>
    <User>
    <Name>David Chris</Name>
    <test>
        <Date>01.02.2009</Date>
        <points>25</points>
    </test>
    <test>
        <Date>14.01.2010</Date>
        <points>231</points>
    </test>
</User>
```

i need to insert another "in this example a third"  Element to the user called "John Smith" with all the sub elements..
so the xml will become :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Users>
    <User>
    <Name>John Smith</Name>
    <test>
        <Date>23.05.2011</Date>
        <points>33</points>
    </test>
    <test>
        <Date>22.06.2011</Date>
        <points>29</points>
    </test>
    <test>
        <Date>30.10.2011</Date>
        <points>21</points>
    </test></b>
    </User>
    <User>
    <Name>David Chris</Name>
    <test>
        <Date>01.02.2009</Date>
        <points>25</points>
    </test>
    <test>
        <Date>14.01.2010</Date>
        <points>231</points>
    </test>
</User>
```

any help is really appreciated ..
thanks a lot ..

Answer (score 2):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        var johnSmith = doc
            .Descendants("User")
            .Descendants("Name")
            .Where(x => x.Value == "John Smith")
            .Select(x => x.Parent)
            .First();

        johnSmith.Add(
            new XElement("test",
                new XElement("Date", "30.10.2011"),
                new XElement("points", "21")
            )
        );
        doc.Save("new.xml");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple (assuming you're using .NET 3.5 or higher):

- Load the document (e.g. using `XDocument.Load`)
- Add the relevant element (create a new `XElement`, find the insertion point, call `insertionPoint.Add(newElement)`)
- Save the document (`XDocument.Save`)

LINQ to XML makes almost all XML-based tasks simpler than older APIs... if the above isn't a good enough start, I'd strongly recommend reading a tutorial on LINQ to XML.

There's no simple way of inserting the new element *without* reading the old file totally, manipulating it and then writing it out totally. In theory you *could* do it in a streaming fashion with `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter`, but they're almost always more trouble than they're worth.

Answer (score 0):

1. For .NET Framework 3.5 and higher: [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx)
2. For .NET Framework 1.1 and higher: [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XElement main = XElement.Load(@"users.xml");

        // write new data to new file
        string newDate = "01.01.2012";
        string newPoints = "42";
        main.Descendants("User")
            .Descendants("Name")
            .Where(e => e.Value == "John Smith")
            .Select(e => e.Parent)
            .First()
            .Add(new XElement("test",
                new XElement("date", newDate),
                new XElement("points", newPoints)
                )
            );

        main.Save("users2.xml");
    }
}
```